# Designing a solution for hierarchy

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse

I have one of the source table in SAP HANA which holds data for client groups and its current hierarchy like cluster, sector, segment type, sub-segment type, BU, profit center, LoS, channel etc. Now over the period client group hierarchy keeps on changing. For e.g. During Jul 19, Client Group "A" was under segment type "Private Business", BU="X", profit center="001", LoS="Tax" and having revenue of £100. During Sep 19, Client Group "A" came under segment type "Equity Business" therefore its profit center got changed to "007" with same BU & LoS.

Having said that, we implemented a dimension to hold these hierarchy but there is no time period involved in that, that means for Client Group "A", you will always see values in current hierarchy for e.g. segment type "Private Equity". It impacts on revenue, as it shows dip £100 for "Private Business" in Jul 19 and growth of £100 for "Equity Business" in Sep 19 in reporting. This issue occurs because fact table during all time periods points to current hierarchy since dimension holds current hierarchy only.

In order to overcome this issue and during analysis, I found there is another table in SAP HANA which records all these hierarchy changes over a period and holds client group hierarchy valid during that point of time. I am planning to create a work table similar to hierarchy dimension with additional columns such as effective_from & effective_to for hierarchy. Then I will join this table with fact using fact's fiscal period to get exact hierarchy and update hierarchy dimension and it hash keys.

Would like to hear more from you guys on whether this approach will work or do I need think differently? Please let me know if need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Create Slowing Changing Type 2 Dimension. Join fact with dimension using a driving date from fact.

Also have a look at:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/2.0.04/en-US/d0b2c5142a19405fb912f71782cd0a84.html

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Short answers with urls are considered low quality and the external content can change. Please edit your answer to include all the key details.